# Passing parameter from one function to another one which uses a different ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

so I have two different classes, in which there are two functions which are using different ViewModels:

DocumentLibraryViewModelFactory class:

```
    public class DocumentLibraryViewModelFactory : IDocumentLibraryViewModelFactory
    {
        private readonly IContentLoader _contentLoader;
        private readonly IDocumentLibraryService _documentLibraryService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IDocumentLibraryCategoriesService _documentLibraryCategoriesService;

        public DocumentLibraryViewModelFactory(
            IContentLoader contentLoader,
            IDocumentLibraryService documentLibraryService,
            IMapper mapper,
            IDocumentLibraryCategoriesService documentLibraryCategoriesService)
        {
            _contentLoader = contentLoader;
            _documentLibraryService = documentLibraryService;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _documentLibraryCategoriesService = documentLibraryCategoriesService;
        }

    private DocumentLibraryViewModel GetDocumentLibraryViewModel(DocumentLibrary content, HomePage homePage, DocumentLibraryFilterResponse<DocumentLibraryFileMetaData> initialData)
        {
            var viewModel = new DocumentLibraryViewModel();

            viewModel.Title = content.Title;
            viewModel.MarketoFormId = content.MarketoFormId;
            viewModel.MarketoFormName = content.MarketoFormName;
            viewModel.Download = content.Download;
            viewModel.AddToBasket = content.AddToBasket;
            viewModel.Print = content.Print;
            viewModel.AllProductCategories = content.AllProductCategories;
            viewModel.AllProducts = content.AllProducts;
            viewModel.AllDocuments = content.AllDocuments;
            viewModel.DisableUrlCategory = content.DisableUrlCategory;
            viewModel.SelectedCategoryTranslation = string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.SelectedCategoryTranslation) ? content.SiteSettings?.SelectedCategoryTranslation : content.SelectedCategoryTranslation;
            viewModel.SortFiles = content.SiteSettings?.SortFiles ?? false;
            viewModel.DocumentFilterPlaceholder = content.DocumentFilterPlaceholder;
            viewModel.IsDocumentFilterDisabled = content.DisableDocumentFilter;

            IContent block = content as IContent;
            viewModel.ContentGuid = block?.ContentGuid.ToString() ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            if (homePage != null)
            {
                // Create product filter.
                viewModel.ProductFilters = new FiltersViewModel();

                // Get and add product categories
                FilterViewModel productCategoriesFilter = _documentLibraryService.GetProductCategoriesFilter(content, homePage);
                viewModel.ProductFilters.List.Add(productCategoriesFilter);

                if (initialData != null)
                {
                    // Create filter for folders/categories.
                    viewModel.Categories = new FiltersViewModel();
                    FilterViewModel categoriesFilter = _documentLibraryCategoriesService.GetCategoriesFilter(content, initialData, homePage);
                    viewModel.Categories.List.Add(categoriesFilter);
                    viewModel.HasCategory = viewModel.Categories.List?.Any() ?? false;

                    // Get and add products
                    FilterViewModel productsFilter = _documentLibraryService.GetProductsFilter(content, initialData);
                    viewModel.ProductFilters.List.Add(productsFilter);

                    viewModel.Files = initialData.Contents;
                    viewModel.HasFiles = viewModel.Files?.Any() ?? false;
                    viewModel.FileExtensions = initialData.FileExtensions?.ToDictionary(fileExtension => fileExtension, fileExtension => fileExtension.ToLower());
                    viewModel.HasFileExtension = viewModel.FileExtensions?.Any() ?? false;
                }

                viewModel.HasProductFilter = viewModel.ProductFilters.List?.Any() ?? false;
            }

            return viewModel;
        }
```

Commerce service class:

```
    public class CommerceService : IDisposable
    {
    public virtual DownloadAndOrderItemsViewModel GetDownloadAndOrderItemsViewModel<T>(T model)
            where T : DownloadAndOrderItems
        {
            var viewModel = new DownloadAndOrderItemsViewModel();
            var downloadList = model?.GetDownloadList();
            if (downloadList?.Any() ?? false)
            {
                viewModel.ProductName = model.ProductName;
                viewModel.Heading = model.Heading;
                viewModel.AddToBasket = model.BasketButton;
                viewModel.Download = model.DownloadButton;
                viewModel.Print = model.PrintButton;
                viewModel.MarketoFormId = model.MarketoFormId;
                viewModel.MarketoFormName = model.MarketoFormName;
                viewModel.Formats = model.GetAllFormats(downloadList);
                viewModel.Categories = new FilterBlock { Filters = model.GetCategories(downloadList) };
                viewModel.DownloadList = downloadList;
                viewModel.SiteSettings = model.SiteSettings;
                viewModel.Print = model.DocumentFilterPlaceholder;
                return viewModel;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

I need to pass a paramater called downloadList from function DownloadAndOrderItemsViewModel (in CommerceService class) to the GetDocumentLibraryViewModel function (inside the DocumentLibraryViewModelFactory class). This function has a initialData.Contents parameter, and I want to combine them both into one list. I just don't know how to do it.

Apologies if my question is stupid, but I am not an experienced programmer (especially in ASP.NET MVC).

Viewmodels:

```
    public class DownloadAndOrderItemsViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A delimiter used to identify levels of categories.
        /// </summary>
        private static string pathDelimiter = "*";

        #region Content

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the product on which the DownloadAndOrderList is placed.
        /// </summary>
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The main heading of the organism.
        /// </summary>
        public string Heading { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The label of a 'secondary' button.
        /// </summary>
        public string AddToBasket { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The label of a 'secondary' button
        /// </summary>
        public string Download { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// A label shown in a header cell of the table where files are listed.
        /// </summary>
        public string Print { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Marketo form ID to be filled in for gated content.
        /// </summary>
        public string MarketoFormId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the Marketo form used for gated content.
        /// </summary>
        public string MarketoFormName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// A dictionary of formats in which files are listed.
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, string> Formats { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The categories under which files are listed.
        /// </summary>
        public FilterBlock Categories { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Markets under which files are listed.
        /// </summary>
        public MarketSelector MarketSelector { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The files listed.
        /// </summary>
        public List<DownloadItem> DownloadList { get; set; }

        public SiteSettings SiteSettings { get; set; }

        public bool IsUrlCatDisabled { get; set; }

        public string SelectedCategoryTranslation { get; set; }

        public string DocumentFilterPlaceholder { get; set; }

        public bool IsDocumentFilterDisabled { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class DocumentLibraryViewModel
    {
        public string PrintValue { get; set; } = "print";

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Headline { get; set; }

        public string MarketoFormName { get; set; }

        public string MarketoFormId { get; set; }

        public FiltersViewModel Categories { get; set; }

        public bool HasCategory { get; set; }

        public FiltersViewModel ProductFilters { get; set; }

        public bool HasProductFilter { get; set; }

        public string Print { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> FileExtensions { get; set; }

        public bool HasFileExtension { get; set; }

        public List<DocumentLibraryFileMetaData> Files { get; set; }

        public bool HasFiles { get; set; }

        public string Download { get; set; }

        public string AddToBasket { get; set; }

        public string AllProductCategories { get; set; }

        public string AllProducts { get; set; }

        public string AllDocuments { get; set; }

        public string ContentGuid { get; set; }

        public bool DisableUrlCategory { get; set; }

        public bool SortFiles { get; set; }

        public string SelectedCategoryTranslation { get; set; }

        public string DocumentFilterPlaceholder { get; set; }

        public bool IsDocumentFilterDisabled { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public string FileType { get; set; }

        public string CheckToSelect { get; set; }

        public string DeepLinkId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DocumentLibraryFilterResponse :

```
    public class DocumentLibraryFilterResponse<T> : FilterResponse<T>
    {
        public DocumentLibraryFilterResponse();

        public DocumentLibraryFilters Filters { get; set; }
        public IList<string> FileExtensions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about **ASP.NET MVC** on the full/classic .NET framework, or about **ASP.NET Core MVC** on the .NET Core framework? You have both tags - which is it?

Comment: This particular app is .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: Removed the confusing `asp.net-core` tag in that case ....

Comment: @marc_s ASP.NET Core targets .NET Standard, so .NET Framework can use it as well. That said, I'm not seeing where any ASP.NET comes into play in this question.

Comment: @cowefe Could you create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DanFriedman It's going to be hard, because the codebase of the project this code snippet is from is enormous, but I will try to add as much relevant code as I can.

Comment: You say you want to pass `documentList` into the other view model, but the other view model doesn't have any members with that type. I know reducing code is hard, but without it, it's also harder for us to give a good answer. Simply put, if you want to pass a parameter to a function, you just add a parameter to the function. But I don't have enough context to understand why this is difficult.

Comment: Well, my problem is that when I want to .Concat those two lists I have mentioned I am getting "List<DocumentLibraryFileMetaData> does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload Queryable.Concat<DownloadItem>(IQueryable<DownloadItem>. IEnumerable<DownloadItem>) requires a receiver of type IQueryable<DownloadItem>" error.